# Aggregation in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using `couchdb` as state db in Hyperledger Fabric. Does hyperledger-fabric chaincode support aggregation queries?

For example:

> lets say I want to run query like `SELECT count from <table> where
>   doc-type="user"`

One way of achieving this is to run a `selector` query and that will return you an iterator and you can find the count with that. That seems to be an ugly method of finding count. Is there any other way to do aggregation calculations?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about the **reduce funtions** are kinda the equivalent to the aggregation functions in relational databases.

Here is more information about it:
https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions

Im not an expert in couchDB but you will probably will use the `_count`

> _count counts the number of emitted values. (It's like _sum for emit(foo, 1).) It ignores the contents of the values, so they can by any type.

Hope that it helps!